# Difference between importing files as RDD vs DF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a confusion regarding importing data in spark.
We can import file in spark using RDD and then convert it into a DF and then register as table and then use SQL on that.
But we can also import data as a DF directly using SQLContext, what's the difference between above two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load data in a dataframe format.

According to itself [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html):

> A DataFrame is a Dataset organized into named columns. It is
> conceptually equivalent to a table in a relational database or a data
> frame in R/Python, but with richer optimizations under the hood.
> **DataFrames can be constructed from a wide array of sources such as:
> structured data files, tables in Hive, external databases, or existing
> RDDs.** The DataFrame API is available in Scala, Java, Python, and R. In
> Scala and Java, a DataFrame is represented by a Dataset of Rows. In
> the Scala API, DataFrame is simply a type alias of Dataset[Row].
> While, in Java API, users need to use Dataset to represent a
> DataFrame.

For example, loading text file how dataframe:

```
>>> import pyspark
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> 
>>> 
>>> sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
>>> sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
>>> df = sqlContext.read.text("file.txt") 
>>> type(df)
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```